# Is it ok to create a tag to help readers ask programming questions related to my book?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, books

My publisher has this old-school forum for readers of my book to ask programming questions related to its content and code samples.

I'd like to direct them over to Stack Overflow, but want a good way to identify them so I can proactively answer them. The book is on Android, so tagging them as such isn't going to help me narrow it down any.

Is it ok to create a tag specifically for the book? The book's title is Professional Android 4 Application Development -- I was going to suggest readers tag their related questions PA4AD.

Comment: I have seen a number of such tags here

Comment: That would mean asking a question about your book, unless you found one?

Comment: No, you have to answer all the Android questions.  ;)

Comment: Fair point Tim. I'd probably just either ask the first forum poster to repost their question on SO and send me the link so I can create the tag, or just repost the question myself and tag it accordingly.

Comment: @BilltheLizard That's my day job. I need to know which ones to answer after hours :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012127/saxparseexception-in-android - is this one about your book @Reto? (Searching for "Professional Android" on SO is a bit... full of book recommendations...)

Comment: You could always ask your publisher to do what Facebook did and get a mini site...

Comment: @RetoMeier I don't see anything wrong with it. I'm not sure about the suggested tag, but your book name is kind of long .. and I can't come up with a better suggestion. Just wait for a few questions to appear and I'm sure the tag will be created (feel free to apply it, as far as I'm concerned).

Comment: @awoodland I've considered that, but I'm not sure that it's worth it. They publish programming books -- I suspect most of the questions readers have would fit right into Stack Overflow.

Comment: @awoodland [I will find you, and I will kill you.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBACYFpqeyU)

Comment: @RetoMeier awoodland is joking, you nor your publisher will *not* get a Facebook-like subdomain.

Comment: @casperOne I know -- was wondering who would flinch first :)

Comment: @Mat Looks likely, but given the date it's probably related to the first edition (I'm up to the 3rd one now). But you've neatly highlighted why I want a tag I can follow.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's a considerable chance that someone finding SO through your invitation *will not* have sufficient reputation to apply the tag if it does not yet exist. I don't see anything wrong with you applying it to the first question because:

- It describes the question
- It's not a meta tag
- It's not like we don't have questions tagged with book titles to begin with (e.g., [sicp](/questions/tagged/sicp), [clrs](/questions/tagged/clrs), [kr-c](/questions/tagged/kr-c))
- It's not like we don't have popular authors that sometimes answer questions about their books here.
- Saving people from cruddy forums is an act of kindness and such questions would probably be on topic.
- You have the rep to do it
- Thanks for promoting SO

If you don't feel comfortable applying the tag, and it should be applied, flag for it.

Just remember, moderation is up to us. Also, I'm not an employee of Stack Exchange, so a subsequent answer from someone that IS an employee takes precedence over this answer.

Comment: On a side note, next time, pick a shorter book title.

Comment: No joke. My preference was "Android" but at the time of the first release "Android" did *not* map to "mobile phones", and the"professional" prefix is a requirement from the publisher.