# I was politely asked not add/create tags that are about a book. What's the reasoning?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I was a politely [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19896312/1243762) by a moderator not to add/create tags that are about a book. The tag/book in question is [real-world-ocaml](/questions/tagged/real-world-ocaml).

I can live with that if it makes sense. Right now it doesn't make sense.

The reason it does not make sense to me is that there is a similar tag for [real-world-haskell](/questions/tagged/real-world-haskell) which has been around and used since [July of 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3273021/1243762).

If a moderator could clarify the reasoning I would appreciate it.

Comment: Moderation is never perfect. Thanks for bringing that tag to our attention, it probably should be burninated.

Comment: Related Question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159048/is-it-ok-to-put-book-titles-in-tags

Comment: The current tag-wiki excerpt by the same moderator pretty much explains the view: *"Please do not use this tag; tags should not be about books or other external sources, but about technologies."*

Comment: All tags should serve a purpose.  I'm not sure what purpose either tag would serve; if you know ocami then you are interested in the question wherever it originates

Comment: Bear in mind that the site has evolved over time, and the scope of the site has with it. Tags concerning books are in questionable area. (I personally think we should keep them, as they say something about the contents of the question.)

Comment: After reading [related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/159048/is-it-ok-to-put-book-titles-in-tags) and this [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/211967/181143) and the comment by Emracool I can make sense of the reasoning, but believe that the book "Real-World-OCaml" will become one of the defining books for OCaml in the same light as SICP or K&R because of the background of the authors. I also agree with Emracool that the we should keep specific book tags because they make it easier to find problems related to the book that others may have encountered.

Comment: So I will avoid creating more book tags, but hopefully putting title of books in the question title won't get them removed by an edit.

Comment: If it's relevant it'll be left if it isn't it'll be edited out. I expect it'll be irrelevant more times than it's relevant

Comment: I noticed you retagged an awful lot of questions with `real-world-haskell` when you hit one of mine.  I reverted the edit (and a few others before getting bored) because the question wasn't *about* the book, I just happened to mention that I got an example from it.  A lot of the other questions you've added that tag to also weren't about the book, and those edits should probably be rolled back.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We use tags around here to mark questions with the things they're *about* -- their topic (or sometimes subject). A question about the book itself is unlikely to be on-topic for Stack Overflow, and the source of the code or the question isn't really important.* The problem itself is what needs to be categorized.

Tagging a question with the name of a book just isn't particularly useful for the way we use tags.

---

*In fact, the book is utterly irrelevant to the question you've linked. Neither the problem nor its solution would change in the slightest if that first sentence were removed.